# program that outputs the different characters (not the ones in common) between 2 strings that read all characters in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
//----------------------
using std :: cin;
using std :: cout;
using std :: endl;
using std::setw ;
//-------------------
const int MAX_STR_LEN=100;
//-----------------------
int main()
{
  char str1 [MAX_STR_LEN];
  char str2 [MAX_STR_LEN];
  int i;
  cin >> setw(MAX_STR_LEN)>>str1;
  cin >> setw(MAX_STR_LEN)>>str2;

      if (strcmp(str1, str2)!=0)
      {
        for (int i=0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
        {
           for (int j=0; j < strlen(str2); j++)
           {
             if (str1[i]==str2[j]) // we want to check whats common first
                                   // and then cout whats left (not common)
             {
                   cout << str2[j];
             }
        }
    }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This works perfectly fine if I'm looking for the common characters. 
I have tried this loop : `if (str1[i]!=str2[j])` but since it's in the `for loops` it gave me the difference between `i` and all of string `j`. For example if `str1=abc` and `str2=abcd` answer should be `d`

Comment: You think you are doing this using C++, but what you are doing is actually C programming with some light C++ flavor. Advice: forget about arrays of char and `strlen()`, `strcmp()` C functions, and use `std::string`.

Comment: If you want to check if two characters differ, change your condition from `str1[i] == str2[j]` to `str1[i] != str2[j]`.

Comment: Common prefix? Or just common characters anywhere in the string (i.e. treating the string as a set of characters)? Be specific about your requirements and show what research you have done into possible solutions to your problem.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus i have tried that, and stated that under my code, the problem with that, is that it will compare one character from the first string and loop over all the characters in the second string, so there will always be a different character in that scenario, what i want is that too take the whole string and compare them together, for instance: abcd and abc, then answer is D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i want to output the character itself that is not common between the two strings. if i understood your question correctly.

Comment: @AncientDragon: That doesn't fully explain your requirement. I asked specific follow-up questions, but in response you simply repeated your original wording. Not useful. If there is a language barrier, perhaps some _examples_ in your question would help.

Answer (score 3):

If you may not change the strings themselves then you can use an approach with `std::set` container. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string s1( "abd" );
    std::string s2( "ace" );

    std::set<char> set1( s1.begin(), s1.end() );
    std::set<char> set2( s2.begin(), s2.end() );

    std::set_symmetric_difference( set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(),
                                  std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout ) );
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
bcde
```

At least the program gives the expected result `d` for strings `abc` and `abcd`.:)

Otherwise you could sort the strings and apply the same standard algorithm `std::set_symmetric_difference`.

Comment: Possibly a very good solution, though he hasn't yet cleared up ambiguity in requirements - might be looking to elide a common prefix instead.

Comment: Better keep using `std::set` then sorting the strings as the elements have to be unique too for [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) could work as expected: "If some element is found m times in [first1, last1) and n times in [first2, last2), it will be copied to d_first exactly std::abs(m-n) times".

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  std::string str1, str2;
  int i;
  getline(cin, str1);
  getline(cin, str2);

  if(str1 != str2)
  {
    bool restart = true;

    while(restart)
    {
        restart = false;
        const int str1Len = str1.size();
        for (int i=0 ; i<str1Len ; i++)
        {
            const int str2Len = str2.size();
            for (int j=0 ; j<str2Len ; j++)
            {
                if (str1[i]==str2[j])
                {
                    str1 = str1.erase(i,1);
                    str2 = str2.erase(j,1);
                    restart = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(restart)
               break;
        }
   }
  }

  cout << "str1: " << str1 << endl;
  cout << "str2: " << str2 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In C++ you can use `std::string` so you don't have to mess around with fixed char arrays. I'm guessing you don't want that. Because you did not tag this as C++11 I did not use for-each loops. I'm sure though it wouldn't change the result.

Comment: I think you can add the first `break;` after the line `restart = true;` avoiding the first `if(restart)`. Maybe you can also adjust the indentation there, becuase it's a little misleading.

Comment: @Bob__ you are right, just improved that answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Writing modern C++ code always produces smaller, and compact code, as compared to writing C code with random bits of C++ thrown in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str1, str2;

    std::getline(std::cin, str1);
    std::getline(std::cin, str2);

    size_t i;

    for (i=0; i<str1.size() && i<str2.size(); ++i)
        if (str1[i] != str2[i])
            break;

    std::cout << str1.substr(i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << str2.substr(i) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of trying to figure out which parts of both strings are different, you will find it much easier, and simpler, to think of the problem on the other end: find out which initial parts of each string are the same with each other. Then what's left is, obviously, your answer.

In the original version, limiting each string to a 100 characters is not important, and does not affect the algorithm, so I left it out. If you still wish to do that, the changes would also be trivial, and I'll leave that part as your homework assignment.

Comment: This isn't modern C++ :D

Comment: Isn't it about looking for all the characters in the strings one by one? Common ones can be at different offsets. In your code you just compare the same offsets between both strings.

Comment: Does not work. Consider `abd` `acd`. Or even simpler `xy` `yz`

Comment: Ignoring the code, the question is asking to exclude the initial common part of both strings. Works just fine for that purpose. If the question was meant to ask something else, it should be rephrased.

Answer (score 0):

its weird, I was going to edit your question but i realized it was the answer. 
You’re missing a end bracket for that first if statement, I put that in.
you're comparing an int to a unsinged int with strlen(), I left it in the conext of 100 character limit, its fine.
int i =0; is not  the Same int as in your for loop, and is unused.I commented that out.
Is there a reason not to use namespace std?
Those other header files were not necessary.
added a line break, so I can see what the output is easily.

I'm not sure what exit_success is, I’d use return 0;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
//----------------------
using namespace std;
//-------------------
const int MAX_STR_LEN=100;
//-----------------------
int main()
{
  char str1 [MAX_STR_LEN];
  char str2 [MAX_STR_LEN];
//  int i;
  cin >> setw(MAX_STR_LEN)>>str1;
  cin >> setw(MAX_STR_LEN)>>str2;

      if (strcmp(str1, str2)!=0)
      {
        for (int i=0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
        {
           for (int j=0; j < strlen(str2); j++)
           {
             if (str1[i]==str2[j]) // we want to check whats common first
                   cout << str2[j];
            }
         }
         cout <<"\n";
       }
  return 0;
}
```

I suspect this is the answer you desired. sure, its C/C++ flavour so what?

Comment: im not looking for the common characters but for the ones that are not. and the program i wrote was one of the ways i thought can get me to the solution, which is by finding the commons first and then another loop that can get me to the the characters that are not common.